# Pass list of environment variables to resource

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

i'm trying to pass a list from my terragrunt.hcl inputs, with environment variables for a container. But i can't get it to work.

terragrunt.hcl:

```
inputs = {
    containers_env = {
        "ENV_TEST" = "testing"
        "ENV_TEST_2" = "testing2"
    }
}
```

main.tf:

```
resource "kubernetes_cron_job" "cronjob" {
    metadata {
        name      = var.metadata_name
        namespace = var.metadata_namespace
    }
    spec {
        schedule                      = var.spec_schedule
        concurrency_policy            = var.spec_concurrencyPolicy
        failed_jobs_history_limit     = var.spec_failedJobsHistoryLimit
        successful_jobs_history_limit = var.spec_successfulJobsHistoryLimit
        job_template {
            metadata {}
            spec {
                template {
                    metadata {}
                    spec {
                        restart_policy                      = var.template_spec_restartPolicy
                        termination_grace_period_seconds    = var.template_spec_terminationGracePeriodSeconds
                        container {
                            name                = var.containers_name
                            image               = var.containers_image
                            image_pull_policy   = var.containers_imagePullPolicy
                            command             = var.containers_command
                            env                 = var.containers_env
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

variables.tf:

```
variable "containers_env" {
    description = ""
    type        = map(string)
}
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Error: Unsupported argument

  on main.tf line 41, in resource "kubernetes_cron_job" "cronjob":
  41:                                                   env                             = var.containers_env

An argument named "env" is not expected here. Did you mean to define a block
of type "env"?
```

Terraform: v0.12.13
Terragrunt: v0.21.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `container` block type seems to require environment variables to be defined as a sequence of nested `env` blocks. Written out manually, they might look something like this:

```
env {
  name  = "ENV_TEST"
  value = "testing"
}
env {
  name  = "ENV_TEST_2"
  value = "testing2"
}
```

To produce these blocks dynamically based on `var.containers_env`, we can use a [`dynamic` block](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#dynamic-blocks), with `var.containers_env` as its repetition expression:

```
dynamic "env" {
  for_each = var.containers_env
  content {
    name  = env.key
    value = env.value
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! I actually tried that yesterday, but when it showed two env blocks in the plan output, i thought it was wrong, so i didn't try applying it, but it worked, thanks for your time :)